# What is a good way to unit test private methods that are not suitable to be extracted as a new class?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, design-patterns, tdd

Roughly speaking I have a class that implements a thread with only one public method `run`. That method goes into a loop, acting like a dispatcher to process network messages one by one; like the following:

```
class WorkerThread {

  public:

    void run() {
      while (!b_shutdown) {
        message = getNextMessage();
        switch(message.type) {
          case WRITE:
            write();
          case READ:
            read();
          // ...
          // more cases to handle
        }
      }
    }


  private:

    void write() { /* logic to test */ }
    void read() { /* logic to test */ }
    // more private methods with logic that needs testing

    // some member variables
};
```

So the main point is that I really don't want to

1. Extract the private methods out to another class, because semantically they are part of this `WorkerThread`.
2. Make the methods public, because they are not used anywhere outside the class.
3. Skip the tests, because it is those methods that implements the main logic.

But how can the private methods be tested elegantly then?

Note:

1. There might have to be a few more public methods to handle the start and termination of the thread, but that is not the concern here.
2. I think this issue is not restricted to `c++`, so I tagged it with the more popular statically typed `Java` as well to get more attention :P

Comment: When building for unit-testing you could make part of the unit-test framework friends of the class to be tested.

Comment: *"so I tagged it with the more popular statically typed Java as well to get more attention"* And generally more downvotes.

Comment: *"because semantically they are part of this WorkerThread"*, It seems not for me, WorkerThread seems just a message dispatcher.

Comment: @RichardCritten yes but I meant to ask a general question about software design rather than a c++ specific one

Comment: Using TDD eliminates this issue, as it prevents you writing private methods that can't be tested. Ultimately you test them via the public interface that calls them. With TDD you would most likely refactor the public interface to move code into prove methods after tests have been written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the question:

> I really don't want to extract the private methods out to another class, because semantically they are part of this WorkerThread.

And that is **wrong**. You are violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Providing "multi threading support" and "doing actual work" are **two** different things. You should **not** enforce that "doing the actual work" is a private implementation detail.

In that sense: the rules that you put up for yourself actually caused you to write **hard to test** code. So, instead of "working around" the symptoms of a bad design - better step back and **fix** your design.

In other words:

- rework your worker thread to be able to run *any* kind of work
- separate concerns; and put "this kind of work" into a specialized class

By doing so, will not only improve your design, you will also make it much easier to test: because now, you can unit test "doing the actual work" **without** any multi-threading complexity. You simply assert that stuff works when done sequentially. Then you test the multi-thread part - on its own; without worrying about the actual work. And in the end, everything comes together nicely.

Instead of you worrying how to test internal implementation details. Which - you don't; the other answer is fully correct there!

Comment: "worker thread to be able to run any kind of work" really enlightened me.

Comment: By the way, may I ask which one is generally considered to be a better design and why - having a private instance of a `IoInterface`, or multiple inheritance from both the worker thread and the `IoInterface`?

Comment: That part is probably "too opinionated". My opinion: I prefer composition over inheritance ... inheritance always leads to very tight coupling; thus, me, personally, I try to avoid it. You don't inherit in order to save coding work; but because some class A actually is some B. Meaning: OO is about "A is-a B" ... because your model tells you that this is the right thing.

Answer (score 10):

Simply put: Don't. Test against the public interface and nothing else. Ultimately that's the only thing that matters.

If you want to see if it's working correctly, the read/write functions should be accessed via an `IoInterface` which can be mocked out for testing.

Comment: That makes some sense, but kind of suggests that in OOP, all private methods can be extracted out to be public methods of another (say `IoInterface`) class, and accessed through a private instance of that class. Is this a reasonable style?

Comment: Nice short/precise answer. And you left out some details for me to write up another answer ; thanks for that ;-)

Comment: @wlnirvana: Each class should have a single reason to change or a single responsibility. It seems WorkerThread is responsible for multithreading and should not be responsible for reading/writing stuff. See GhostCat's  great answer for details.